# OpenLayer: How to create Features from WKT (Linestring)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openlayers-3, multilinestring, wkt

I am very new to using OpenLayers and new to mapping. I am trying to create a simple map that is getting data from a postgresSQL. The data is then returned into a textarea (Linestring ........). I want to use the result to draw a line on the map.

So far I didn't have any luck making this happen. I can see the returned data from the database using console log.

Any working example/how to using WKT(linestring) OpenLayers 3 will be appreciated.

```
My HTML
<div class="map" id="map"></div>
<form action="#">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" id="resultTxtArea" readonly rows="30"
                type="text"></textarea> <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for=
                "resultTxtArea">Text lines...</label>
            </div>
</form>
```

[image: Javascript 2/1]
[image: javascript 2/2]

Comment: check this online parser and viewer. https://ptsagkis.github.io/spatial-formats-parser/

Answer (score 1):

Use the `readFeature` method from `ol.format.WKT` object ([Documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WKT-WKT.html)):

```
// some example linestring as WKT
var linestringWKT = 'LINESTRING(4 6,7 10)';
// get the feature
var feature = new ol.format.WKT().readFeature(linestringWKT);
```